# Displaying LaTeX equations with EWW

Tags: latex, images, eww

I've been using EWW and I noticed that it displays inline LaTeX expressions ($ ... $) but it fails to display those that have their own line ($$ ... $$). I'm attaching a print below. Have a look the blank space after the sentence "Symbolically, ".

I'm very new to Emacs, EWW, and text-based browsers so I have the following questions:

- Is it possible to display those $$ ... $$ LaTeX formulas?
- Can I choose whether I want to see the LaTeX code or the rendered version?

[image]

Comment: Neither Firefox nor EWW is rendering TeX. The inline expressions are pure HTML (e.g. `<b>A</b><sup>1</sup>` for A^1) and the standalone expressions are images.

Comment: I see. So why aren't all the standalone formulas displayed in eww as images?

Comment: I'm not sure, can you reproduce from `emacs -Q`? Some causes off the top of my head are 0) running Emacs under a text terminal; 1) disabling HTML image rendering via variables like `shr-inhibit-images`/`shr-blocked-images`; 2) omitting some images by calling `eww-readable`; 3) image foreground is same colour as buffer background; 4) something else in your configuration or installed packages is somehow interfering; 5) Emacs is built without image support or has a bug; 6) etc. FWIW, I can't reproduce on latest Emacs development snapshot.

Comment: Looks like it's some variant of option 5 (lack of image support or bug), the image loads fine for me on Emacs 26 and 27 but not in 25.

Comment: I'm running version 25.2.2 so that's it... Thanks!

Comment: I came here looking to see if it was possible to render MathJax LaTeX inside of EWW. This question doesn't seem to be about that, but that led me googling around long enough to find [texfrag](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/texfrag).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is [bug#24111](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24111), which was fixed for Emacs 26 in ["Fix rendering of some complex SVG images"](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=267c98ae4849e87bcee49ebbb7adcf211c60cd47) of 2017-01-24.

It is always recommended to use the latest Emacs version possible, especially in the context of browsing the web, but in the meantime I think you can hack around this issue on Emacs 25 with the following advice:

```el
(define-advice shr-parse-image-data (:around (fn &rest args) my-emacs-25-patch)
  "Hackaround for bug#24111 in Emacs 25."
  (if shr-blocked-images
      (apply fn args)
    (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'libxml-parse-xml-region) #'buffer-substring)
              ((symbol-function 'shr-dom-to-xml)          #'identity))
      (apply fn args))))
```